# How can I solve $1/x = \ln x$?

Tags: calculus

Another way to look at it is  $x^x  =  e$.

It seems possible, but I really don't know.  It seems very helpful to know the exact value where a function's y value is the same as its slope.

Comment: You can't. $\qquad$

Comment: You can find many duplicates of that question on MSE! Also you can use https://approach0.xyz/search/ to find that.

Comment: @Robert Kaman in that case just search for an answer and delete that one. If you are interested to discuss or clarify some particular point you can raise that here.

Comment: @Robert Kaman $x^x = e$ has only one real solution around $x = 1.763$

Comment: There are several (actually infinitely many) complex solutions to the equation, but there is only one real solution, written as $x=e^{\operatorname{W}(1)}$, where $\operatorname{W}(z)$ is the Product Log Function. Here's a link to more info on this function: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LambertW-Function.html

Comment: @clathratus this should be the answer, not a comment. Go for it!

Comment: @LarryB ok... if you insist.

Comment: IMO, knowing where a function equals its slope is anecdotal and of little practical use. On the opposite, the function that equals is slope *everywhere* (more generally a fixed multiple of the slope) is of a fundamental importance in calculus and applications of the dynamics of linear systems.

Comment: but you can find a sequence that tends to the zero of $xln(x)-1$ by using Newton or Secant method

Answer (score 3):

Per the comment of clathratus, the Lambert W function is relevant here; since $x\ln x=1$, take $x=1/W(1)$ for some branch $W$ of the function. However, if you actually want a few decimal places of $x$ in a hurry, numerical methods such as the Newton-Raphson method are prudent. Define $f(x):=x\ln x-1$ so $f'=\ln x+1$ and $g(x):=x-\frac{f(x)}{f'(x)}=\frac{x+1}{\ln x+1}$; then we can use the recursion $x_{n+1}=g(x_n)$ (which is probably what ab123 did), provided we choose a sensible seed. The choice $x_0$ should do.

Answer (score 2):

green line is a $y=e$ and blue line is graphic for function $x^x$
[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are several (actually infinitely many) complex solutions to the equation, but there is only one real solution, written as $x=e^{\operatorname{W}(1)}$, where $\operatorname{W}(z)$ is the Product Log Function. Here's a link to more info on this function: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LambertW-Function.html

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
Use the iteration method as follow
$$x_{i+1}=e^{\frac{1}{x_{i}}}$$
start with $x_0=1$

After $40$ iterations the value of $x$ will be $1.763222834$

Answer (score 1):

You may also use numerical integration: the wanted solution is $\frac{1}{W(1)}$ with $W$ being Lambert's function, [hence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) by the Lagrange inversion theorem

$$ x = \left[\left(\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{dt}{\pi^2+(e^t-t)^2}\right)^{-1}-1\right]^{-1}. $$
The integrand function behaves like the normal distribution close to the origin, like the Laplace distribution over $t\gg 0$ and like the Cauchy distribution over $t\ll 0$. This leads to $x\approx 1.76322$.

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved either by using **Lambert W function** or **Newton Raphson method**.
The above equation can be written as -> 1 = x*ln(x)

**1. (Using Lambert W function):**

W(x*ln(x)) = W(1)     ---- [1]

as per Lambert W function: W(x*ln(y)) = ln(y)

hence,
ln(x) = W(1)    *{substituting in [1]}*

so, 
x = e^(W(1))

but **W(1) is approximately equal 0.56714329**
refer: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function;

substituting the value (W(1)) above:

**x = 1.76322** (approximate value)

**2. (Newton Raphson Method):**

consider f(x) = x*ln(x) - 1 & solve further using Newton Raphson Method formula for different values of x, starting with 0.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method

Hope this helps!